# Header video in .m4v format doesn't play in IE 11

Tags: javascript, html, video, internet-explorer-11

I have a problem that IE11 isn't playing my html5 video tag video. I've tried other browsers like Chrome/Firefox and there it works perfectly fine. IE11 doesn't even give me an error in the console why it isn't playing the video and shows me white background. I tried different formats like .m4v and mp4. The video is in h264 encoding and web optimized(I'm using software named "Handbrake" to encode the video"), the resolution is 1920x1088. I also tried to put "" in my website head.

My HTML code

```
<video autoplay loop muted id="player">

</video>
 <img id="backfill-image" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/backgroundimage.jpg"> 
</div>
```

My JavaScript

```
let myPlayer;
let backfill;

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {

myPlayer = document.getElementById("player");
backfill = document.getElementById("backfill-image");

 myPlayer.onerror = function() {
   console.error(myPlayer.error);
   showPlaceholderImage();
};

// Example invalid source to throw an error
myPlayer.src = ""+templateUrl+"/img/myvideo.m4v";
 // Example valid source that doesn't throw an error 
 // myPlayer.src = "https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4";


 function showPlaceholderImage() {
   myPlayer.style.display = "none";
    backfill.style.display = "block";
 }



});
```

Comment: So there is no possibilty to play HTML5 video in IE?

Comment: There are some, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to make a test with the MP4 format H264 encoder video.

It looks like it is working fine on the IE 11 browser.

Here is a test code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
</head>
<body> 
 <video width="400" autoplay>
   <source src="https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/1080/Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_5MB.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
   Your browser does not support HTML video.
 </video>
</body> 
</html>
```

Here, you can see that I have verified that the video has an H264 encoder using a VLC player.

[image]

Output in the IE 11 browser:

[image]

Video downloaded from [this site](https://test-videos.co.uk/)

Comment: That's an interesting tip indeed but as I checked my video file codec it is H264 as i expected. Maybe the problem is that my video is full width 1920x1088?

Comment: If it possible for you then can you please share your sample video link here. We can try to make a test with it to check for the results. It may help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: It turns out that my WordPress site isn't loading JavaScript on any of the computers, I'm trying to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for updating us with the current status of the issue. I suggest you can check whether your site loading the JS with other browsers or not. If it is IE specific issue then Go to Internet options-> Security tab-> Select the proper zone and click on the Custom level button. Find and check whether the 'Active scripting' option is enabled or not. If not then enable it and again check for the issue. Also, check the browser console to see whether it is showing any error messages.