# Change ID css in IE with JavaSCript

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, display

I'm trying to figure out how to change css display from none to block with javascript but only for IE. Currently I have this code but it won't change the CSS on ID #backfill-image.

```
<script>
function isIE() {
  ua = navigator.userAgent;
  /* MSIE used to detect old browsers and Trident used to newer ones*/
  var is_ie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ") > -1 || ua.indexOf("Trident/") > -1;

  return is_ie; 
}
/* Create an alert to show if the browser is IE or not */
if (isIE()){

document.getElementById("backfill-image").style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your code working fine for me. IE11 blocks scripts sometimes, you should see a popup at the bottom of browser after opening website if that's reason. You can also add console log to methods to be sure.

Comment: Did you check if `isIE()` actually resolves to `true`?

Comment: It was working with alert but doesn't change my css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be a caching related issue on your end. Try to press **CTRL + F5** key to hard refresh the page.

Your code is working on my side.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
<style>
#backfill-image
{
 display:none;
}
</style>

</head>
<body> 
 <div id="backfill-image"><h2>This is my sample text...</h2></div>

<script>
function isIE() {
  ua = navigator.userAgent;
  /* MSIE used to detect old browsers and Trident used to newer ones*/
  var is_ie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ") > -1 || ua.indexOf("Trident/") > -1;

  return is_ie; 
}
/* Create an alert to show if the browser is IE or not */
if (isIE()){

document.getElementById("backfill-image").style.display = "block";
}
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Output in the Ie 11 browser:

[image]

If the issue persists then try to make a test with my posted code to see whether it is working or not.

Edit:

IE does not support the => Arrow functions. You need to change the syntax or transpile your code. You can use Babel to transpile the code. Ref: [babeljs.io](https://babeljs.io/) Helpful thread: [Why doesn't this arrow function work in IE 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40216015/why-doesnt-this-arrow-function-work-in-ie-11)

Also, inform us whether the issues in the other threads solved or not.

Comment: It turns out that I.E isn't loading the JavaScript for some reason on any of the computers. I'm using WordPress, I tried to deactivate some plugins and updating but no luck. I have a feeling that the problem is with WordPress but can't be 100% sure.

Comment: Can you please check whether the 'Active scripting' option is enabled or not in a similar way as I suggested to you in this thread? Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62279520/header-video-in-m4v-format-doesnt-play-in-ie-11

Comment: Active scripting is enabled, I'm trying to figure out what's going on with the javascript because one part of the code is breaking the entire javascript but only for I.E.

Comment: It can be possible that your JS code using something that is not supported in the IE browser may cause this issue.

Comment: Yes that is absolutely true, I think the problem is with this line "window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) =>". Which is weird because the JS document suggests that IE supports this.

Comment: IE does not support the => Arrow functions. You need to change the syntax or transpile your code. You can use Babel to transpile the code. Ref: https://babeljs.io/ Helpful thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40216015/why-doesnt-this-arrow-function-work-in-ie-11#:~:text=IE11%20doesn't%20support%20them,Use%20function%20functions%20instead.&text=IE%20doesn't%20support%20the,your%20ES6%20codes%20to%20ES5.

Comment: You're a legend! Such a simple solution and that is really good to know. Got the code working with babel. Thanks!